# Blocks hides the content of social links when we changed the region in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am working on http://softprodigy.in/kalani site made in drupal 7 using omega theme. i am facing one major problem on some pages,for example on this page http://softprodigy.in/kalani/guest-information, under content region there is block of social sharing links that are displayed in block,i want to change the region but whenever i changed the region content goes somewhere and div displays empty with no content.I don't know whats the problem.If anyone knows any solution please share it with me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found one thing that these social links are implemented thorugh add this toolbox but when i changed the region it excluded the js file and stops showing social links.please share your views.

Answer (score 0):

The blocks that contain hidden images look like they have been added manually. So, you need to change the input mode for the block content.

The best way is to use PHP code; Go to your modules page and enable `PHP filter module`.

The in the block configuration page type something like inside the block content textarea:

```
 global $base_path;
 print "<img src='<?php print $base_path ?>sites/default/files/image.jpg' />";
```

OR

```
 print theme("image", array("path" => "sites/default/files/image.jpg"));
```

Hope this helps.